# ModelAndView in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am going through the Spring API. I went through the ModelAndView class. I found there two mehods in the class which return Map. One is getModel() and other is getModelInternal(). They both return Map. What is the difference between these methods. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check javadoc for methods:

```
/**
 * Return the model map. May return {@code null}.
 * Called by DispatcherServlet for evaluation of the model.
 */
protected Map<String, Object> getModelInternal() {
    return this.model;
}

/**
 * Return the model map. Never returns {@code null}.
 * To be called by application code for modifying the model.
 */
public Map<String, Object> getModel() {
    return getModelMap();
}
```

So, one be called by client - another by framework, one nullable - another not-null.

Comment: Can you please elobrate on this , what do we mean by called by application. Means for example if we add an Object say Employee in the Mode what value is returned by both the methods.

Comment: getModel is to be used by your code (and it is not-null),  getModelInternal it to ve used by Spring DispatcherServlet (part of Spring) and may be nullable. So, just use getModel()